# Dockerfile with docker-compose.yml

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, yaml, ini

In general, I do have an understanding of the purposes behind using Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml. However, I am facing some issues with using both at the same time. Likely, I'm just not specifying all the locations correctly.

I built an app that takes a config.ini file as one of the inputs (it should be located in the same directory as my app.py code). My goal is to avoid re-building the image every time I made changes to the config file. I understand that I can do it by building an image and then running/restarting the container via docker-compose.yml.

Below is the structure of my project:

```
my_local_dir_with_py_projects/
|__config.ini
|__docker-compose.yml
|__my_py_app/
   |__app.py
   |__requirements.txt
   |__Dockerfile
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR app/

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  py_app:
    image: py_app:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "./config.ini:/Users/my_user/my_local_dir_with_py_projects/config.ini:z" 
    ports:
      - "5005:5000"
    command: python3 app.py
```

I have built an image via `docker build --tag py-app .` being in `/Users/my_user/my_local_dir_with_py_projects/py_app`. I then `cd /Users/my_user/my_local_dir_with_py_projects/` and running my `.yml` file via `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up`.

Thank you for your help.

Edit: Just to clarify the issue. I am getting the following error:

```
py_app_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
py_app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/configparser.py", line 790, in get
py_app_1  |     value = d[option]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py", line 986, in __getitem__
py_app_1  |     return self.__missing__(key)            # support subclasses that define __missing__
py_app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py", line 978, in __missing__
py_app_1  |     raise KeyError(key)
py_app_1  | KeyError: 'base_url'
...
```

A part of my config.ini file:

```
[DEFAULT]
base_url = https://api.binance.com
klines_url = /api/v1/klines
```

Which I am reading via:

```
import configparser 
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
```

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The issue is that it seems app.py can't see ini file that I specify via volumes, because it's throwing a KeyError and 'base_url' is my very first variable in config.ini.

Comment: I think you will need to show us your `config.ini` file as well? Because it looks like your app is reading the file fine, but is running into an error.

Comment: Just added it at the end of the post. The reason I think the issue is not with the config file is because when I build an image with config.ini in in and don't include volumes in the .yml file, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Dockerfile, you're installing the application into `/app`.  Your Compose setup mounts the config file into a `/Users/...` directory, but your application doesn't know anything about this directory; it's running inside `/app` and presumably is looking for the `config.ini` file there.

So in your `docker-compose.yml` file, this line:

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./config.ini:/app/config.ini
  #              ^^^^
```

needs to match this line in your Dockerfile:

```yaml
WORKDIR /app
#       ^^^^
```

(It's probably clearer to use an absolute path in the Dockerfile as I've shown.  It's also better practice to put a `CMD` in the Dockerfile than to depend on a `command:` override showing up in the `docker-compose.yml` file.)

Comment: Thank you, David! This solved the problem. Seems so obvious now, but I feel like I tried everything except this. I read somewhere that on the right hand side, after `:`, one should be specifying the location of file on the local drive, while it's the other way around.